# refresh UI after change observable array in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I heave this in html tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts"
and Knockout view model

```
var viewModel = function () {
    $this = this;
    $this.contacts = ko.observableArray();

$this.nextPage = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/AddressBook",
            data: { pagesize: pageSize, currentpage: CPage },
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function (data) {

            var myKoObservableArray = $this.contacts; 

            myKoObservableArray.push(null);
            myKoObservableArray.push(data);

           alert(data[0].Name);

        });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/AddressBook",
        data: { pagesize: 10,currentpage: 0 },
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function (data) {

        var vm = new viewModel();
        vm.contacts(data);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
});
```

First time page is loaded, table is filled from ajax call from $(document).ready. 
When I call nextPage from UI I make ajax call and alert(data[0].Name) show first element from returned data array. Is is different collection returned from server each time. The problem is that my table in UI not changed after change "contacts" observable array from second(and next) ajax call.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can call valueHasMutated function for your array:

```
yourArray.valueHasMutated();
```

If first didn't help you can do 'dirty' refresh:

```
self.refresh = function(){
    var data = self.array().slice(0);
        self.array([]);
        self.array(data);
    };
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/FuEy6/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
myKoObservableArray.push(null);
```

Why are you doing this?

```
myKoObservableArray.push(data);
```

This adds a single element to the end `contacts`, namely a single reference to the entire array you received.

It sounds like you want to replace the contents of `contacts` with the array you got from your ajax call. If that's so, just replace those two statements with

```
$this.contacts(data);
```

If instead you want to append the new items to the existing ones, than use

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(v) {$this.contacts.push(v)});
```

Comment: I tried $this.contacts(data) and alert(data[0].FirstName) and alert show correct new name after each call of ajax method. Problem is that UI of table not update.I tried this http://ryanrahlf.com/knockout-js-observablearray-not-updating-the-ui-heres-how-to-fix-it/ but again UI not updated

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that script file was included twice - at header and at bottom of the page. This probably broke binding.